# how to load the reuters dataset in R

Tags: r, keras

this is the reuters dataset referred to in "Deep Learning with R" as

```
library(keras)
reuters <- dataset_reuters(num_words = 10000)
```

this does not work as the dataset is not hosted on google anymore. what is the recommended way to get it? do I get it in python and export as csv locally or try the python code under reticulate? or is there a way to provide the correct url to the dataset_reuters() function?
or should I be alerting the Rstudio folks to fix their keras module?
Cheers
S.